# How to bypass parsing while setting innerHTML in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, parsing, innerhtml

**Disclaimer**:
I read a lot of stuff regarding parsing and bypassing of `[innerHTML]` in Angular.
Found few solutions which includes creating a pipeline and bypass the URL or HTML etc.

Still not able to find out a good solution.

**Problem**:
While providing my HTML to `DOMParser()` or setting directly the HTML, it parses it (by default) which leads to inappropriate/unwanted results.

I have HTML which contains this line.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="text-align:left;font-size: 15px;" width="100%"> <tbody>${shipmentData.order_items.map((items, i)=>{return ` <tr>...</tr>`})}
```

While passing this to `DOMParser` or `innerHTML` it gets converted into below code

```
${shipmentData.order_items.map((items, i)=&gt;{return ` `}).join('')}<table style="text-align:left;font-size: 15px;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> <tbody><tr>
```

I tried many solutions as stated above in disclaimer and also tried setting things using `replaceChildren() or append()` etc., but none gets the output I want.

**Is there any way around to set HTML without parsing to any element?**

Comment: There is no way to set HTML without parsing it, except as a string. IOW, you could append it to `textContent` and it would be converted to `&lt;table border="0" cellpadding="0" ...` such that it was display in the HTML document as text...

Comment: How exactly do you want it to turn out?

Comment: Thanks for your response @HereticMonkey @zer00ne
@HererticMonkey -> I tried this way out but does not matter, it will eventually convert the textContent to innerHTML with parsing it.
See, the problem is not that it should not parse.

@zer00ne -> The problem is when i am using variables in html containing loop why this is packed just like i displayed in the next section.

Mostly it converts ```=>``` to ```=&gt;``` which is what not majorly working when i am using ```eval()```

Comment: Note that only the first person you @ mention is notified, so @zer00ne was not notified in the comment above. This comment will notify them.

Comment: You got the problem rt? @HereticMonkey

Comment: No. It is not something I can reproduce. But you threw in that you are using `eval()` now, which wasn't present in your question. I think you should [edit] your question to be clear exactly what you're trying to do, and how you are trying to do it, with code demonstrating it, in a [mre]. Use something like StackBlitz if you must, but be sure to include the necessary code here.